# Checking for a new Ubuntu release There is no development version of an LTS available

Tags: apt, 18.04, 20.04, upgrade, updates

We are upgrading OS version from 18.04 to 20.04 LTS .When we try to run do-release-upgrade -c , we are getting the following error :

*Checking for a new Ubuntu release There is no development version of an LTS available. To upgrade to the latest non-LTS development release set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.*

We need to have LTS release .

We tried with do-release-upgrade -d but this is also not working .

It is showing :

***Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts.***

Please help us here .

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 is EOL. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: But the link provided is also not able to solve the issue , tried with http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ but still not able to run do-release-upgrade

Comment: Try http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/  for bionic

Comment: Classic misuse of the `-d` flag. See `man do-release-upgrade`. I suggest you omit that attempt from your question, since it unrelated to your actual `-c` question.

Comment: What happens when you run `do-release-upgrade` without any flags at all? Please show complete output.

Comment: FYI:  The `-d` upgrade is required until *after* Ubuntu 20.04.1 has been released which was some time ago (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/06/ubuntu-20-04-1-lts-released/) as the normal upgrade path opens after 20.04.1 release, with the `-d` required before then to *force* the upgrade. Some documentation exists telling you to do it, as it was required before August 2020 when https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts was amended.